# how to find hidden event firing in javascript - kendo grid

Tags: javascript, jquery, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

i just want to replicate one of the functionality called multiple row selection by using combination of two keys (shift + UpArrow/DownArrow) that available in [here](https://dojo.telerik.com/).

but i am not able to find the what is the exact event triggered from min.js file.

so far i tried with below. but its not firing the event. debugger trigger on pressing 'shift' key but its not considering arrow keys.

```
 $("#kgrid").data("kendoGrid" ,"table").bind("keydown", function(e){
           var arrows = [ 38, 39, 40];
           if (e.shiftKey && ($.inArray(e.which, arrows) >= 0)){
              console.log("shiftkey + arrow");
              }
           // console.log('key-ing');
          });
```

in my old version, its supporting shift +click only. could some tell me how find this event?

I am currently using kendo version v2017.1.118, but the functionality what am looking is in v2018.1.221.  how to override this.

Comment: Are you using `selectable: "multiple, row"`?

Comment: @DontVoteMeDown yeah am using that.and its defined in kendo command[]

Comment: I've made [this demo](https://dojo.telerik.com/IGExazIt) but I can't figure why it doesn't works with `multiple, row`.

Comment: i saw your demo. but no luck bro. atleast if could find the "shift+click" combination in version of kendo, i can try to modify it.. but no luck as of now

Answer (score 0):

This answers part of your question, getting keydown to fire when "multiple, row" is selected.

From

https://www.telerik.com/forums/keydown-event

"With multiple selection enabled, the mousedown event is prevented, and the Grid table cannot be focused. I can suggest manually focusing the table in the change event of the Grid:"

I tweaked the demo that DontVoteMeDown supplied

https://dojo.telerik.com/IGExazIt/8

If you copy this into a text file on your system and run it in a browser you'll get a stack trace but that doesn't help much

```
console.trace
(anonymous) @ result:17
dispatch @ jquery-1.12.3.min.js:3
r.handle @ jquery-1.12.3.min.js:3
```

If you just want to select multiple rows the documentation covers that
https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/grid/methods/select

e.g.
https://dojo.telerik.com/ATOsULAL